# How to define a class-level macro in a module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, reflection, module, include, extend

In the Ruby programming language, I am creating a class with a class-level macro, as follows:

```
class Timer 
  def self.add_time
    def time
      STDERR.puts Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")      
    end 
  end 
end
```

The class method `add_time`, when executed, will generate a `time` method.
Now, I can execute that class-level macro in another class `Example` as follows:

```
class Example < Timer 
  add_time 
end
```

When I now call `time` on an instance of class `Example`, the `time` method is present there, as I intended:

```
ex = Example.new 
ex.time
```

and prints the current time: `23:18:38`.

But now I would like to put the `add_time` macro in a module and still have the same overall effect.  I tried with an `include` like this:

```
module Timer 
  def self.add_time
    def time
      STDERR.puts Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")      
    end 
  end 
end 

class Example 
  include Timer
  add_time
end 

ex = Example.new 
ex.time
```

but then I receive an error that the method `add_time` is not defined on the class `Example`: `NameError: undefined local variable or method ‘add_time’ for Example:Class`. So then I tried with an `extend` instead like this:

```
class Example 
  extend Timer
  add_time
end
```

but it gives me a similar error.

So the question is: *How can I get the same effect as in my original example where the `Timer` was defined as a class, but using a module instead?*

Comment: When a class includes a module the module's instance methods become instance methods of the class. When a class extends a module the module's instance methods become class methods of the class. In performing both of those actions the module's module methods are disregarded.

Comment: @CarySwoveland So you mean that the method ```self.add_time``` will get disregarded upon inclusion or extension because it is not an instance method but a module method?

Comment: I can make it to work by defining ```def add_time``` as an instance method of the module and then do ```Example.include Timer```. Then I need to do ```ex.add_time``` to add the ```time``` method to the instance ```ex```. But that is not what I want because I want the ```time```method to be available for all instances of my ```Example``` class.

Comment: Yes, to answer your first comment. Regarding the second, make `add_time` an instance method of `Timer`, as you say, then `Example.extend Timer` to make `add_time` a class method of `Example`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I tried that too but it doesn't seem to work. Have a module ```Timer``` with an instance method ```add_time```. Then do ```Example.extend Timer``` to make ```add_time``` a class method of ```Example```. And finally, to call ```Example.add_time```. However, when I do that, the method ```time``` gets defined as a class method, not as an instance method. So ```ex.time``` still doesn't work. However, I did find a solution that seems to work by making clever use of ```class_eval```. I'll post that as my solution. Thanks for helping me find that solution.

Comment: You have several choices. If you include `Timer` then `add_time` becomes an instance method of `Example` (which I'm sure you understand). If `add_time` is merely a helper method whose return value does not depend on the instance of `Example`, you could extend `Timer`, making `add_time` a class method, which can be invoked `i.class.add_time` if `i` is an instance of `Example`.  Alternativerly, make `add_time` a module method of `Timer` and invoke it `Timer.add_item` (from anywhere). That's how, for example, the methods of `Math` are used, all of which are module methods (e.g., `Math.gamma(9)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CarySwoveland pointed out, the method `def self.add_time` in the `module Timer` gets disregarded upon inclusion or extension in a class. Only the module's instance methods are added to the class as instance method of the class (in case of inclusion) or as class methods of the class (in case of extends).

```
module Timer 
  def add_time # INSTANCE METHOD !
    def time
      STDERR.puts Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")      
    end 
  end 
end
```

So the first step of the solution is to declare the method `def add_time` as an instance method of the module. Next, we extend the class `Example` with that module, so that the module's instance method gets added as a class method in the class `Example`, and we call the `add_time`method:

```
class Example 
  extend Timer # EXTEND INSTEAD OF INCLUDE
  add_time
end
```

However, this doesn't quite work as desired yet as the `time` method has now been generated as a class method: `Example.time` prints the current time `01:30:37`, but an instance `ex` of class `Example` does not understand the method `time`.

The solution is thus to generate the method `def time` as an instance method rather than as a class method. This can be done using `class_eval`, which leads us to the following working solution:

```
module Timer 
  def add_time # INSTANCE METHOD !
    self.class_eval do # USE class_eval TO DEFINE AN INSTANCE METHOD !
      def time
        STDERR.puts Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")      
      end 
    end 
  end
end 

class Example 
  extend Timer # USE EXTEND TO ADD add_time AS A CLASS METHOD
  add_time
end 

ex = Example.new 
ex.time
```